# Power BI: Sign up windows spams (free desktop user)

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

First all first, I am free Power BI desktop user, so I am not Signed in and don't have an account in Power BI.

Since last Update I encountered an issue, and that is spamming with Sign in window anytime I am trying to use some templates that I downloaded from internet. I NEVER had this issue before, I could open all the templates (pbix files) without any trouble, but not since I open I am constantly getting Sign in window and can't get rid of it actually. So, I must terminate app to close it.

I tried to reinstall, to fix it, but problem is still there. Do anyone got an idea what could be a problem? Is Microsoft "blocked" usage of custom visuals for free users or something?

Comment: you can turn off the prompt to sign up that may help, you will need to edit the registry https://gist.github.com/jasonadsit/85e33212fb704355aa79ad6dc2bea1ee or [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft Power BI Desktop]
"UpdateCheckUrl"

Comment: @Jon Thanks!! It solved by itself, update for June was and it dissapeared...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After UPDATE for June 2020, problem solved automatically!

Thanks to Microsoft =)